# Redux Toolkit - createAsyncThunk async with parameters

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have the following case:

```
const obj = {
  order:order, 
  token:user.token
};
dispatch(saveOrder(obj));
```

and:

```
const initialState = {
  order: [],
  status: 'idle',
  error:''
};

export const saveOrder = createAsyncThunk(
  'order/saveOrder',
  async (obj) => {  
      const {order, token} = obj;
        try {
          const response = await tshirts.post('/orders.json?auth=' + token, order);
          console.log('response', response.data);
          return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
          return error;
        }
      }
)
export const saveOrderSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'order',
  initialState,

  reducers: {},

  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(saveOrder.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = 'loading';
      })
      .addCase(saveOrder.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'idle';
        state.order = action.payload;

        if (action.payload.message) {
          state.error = action.payload.message;
          state.order = [];
        }
      })
      .addCase(saveOrder.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'idle';
        state.error = action.payload.message;
        state.order = [];
      });
  },
});

export default saveOrderSlice.reducer;
```

I get an error:
"Uncaught TypeError: action is undefined"

I don't understand what's wrong. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Where are your reducers? There should be a reducer with the action.

Comment: You're right, I added the reducers now.

Comment: Have you connected this slice into the main root reducers

Comment: Yes, I have, thank you for the quick response.

Comment: are you ts or js? Sometimes on TS you will want to make the dispatch into a dispatch relative to your app so that it knows whats inside of it otherwise you can get an action type error

Comment: I use JS only, no Typescript.

Comment: in initial state i think stats is suppose to be loading:"idle", https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk.